# ssh settings `permitopen="localhost:4000"` does not limit remote port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, access-control

I have a special user on my server, let's call it `foo`. I use it only for port forwarding.

The user's `.ssh/authorized_keys2` is set up to prevent login and to open only a specific port:

```
no-pty,no-X11-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:4000",\
command="/bin/echo do-not-send-commands" ssh-rsa <long public key> bar@foobar
```

Additionally, the `foo` has its shell set to `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd`.

I can't log onto the machine (that's what I want):

```
$ ssh foo@remote
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Connection to remote closed.
```

But I can open ports. Interestingly, I can open port 4000, but also other unprivileged ports:

```
$ ssh -N -R 4001:localhost:22 foo@remote
> # connection established
```

On `remote` with user `bar`, I can connect:

```
$ ssh -p4001 bar@localhost
bar@localhost's password:
Last login: Fri Sep 26 09:23:45 2014 from localhost.localdomain
...
```

> Why can user `foo` open port 4001, when I limited it to `permitopen="localhost:4000"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, re-reading the manual reveals the cause:

```
permitopen="host:port"
    Limit local ``ssh -L'' port forwarding....
```

Also mentioned in this U&L Q&A titled: [How can I limit ssh *remote* port forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59683/how-can-i-limit-ssh-remote-port-forwarding).