# Information/Assistance required on reverse SSH Tunneling (Naming Conventions etc)

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunneling

I have multiple raspberry pi's running Arch Linux (No GUI) in which I need to access. These pi's are behind firewalls in each unique location. Currently I use openvpn to connect to these but the costs of that system is expensive per license. I use the access server from them.

As a result, I am trying to design and setup a system that allows me the ability to login to my VPN server (vps) and run a command to search for a specific name (OfficeDevice1991) such as: `customcommandsearch "OfficeDevice1991"` and then it then returns the IP address of the machine or something I can use to SSH into with. I am also looking for the ability to run a command to list every active connected device. It lists back the IP, name and perhaps how long it's been active for.

For this goal, I of course need to create something that includes the name of the device (in this case OfficeDevice1991) and then that pi will be able to hook into my vps public server. From the public server, I can log in and do a search of every device connected to it and return information required to ssh into.

I have been looking into reverse SSH and so far I got one of my test pi's connected and accessible from my vps using the following commands:

PI:

```
ssh -fN -R 12345:localhost:22 -i /publickeyfile useraccount@ip //Pi's command to connect to vpn
```

VPS:

```
ssh -p 12345 useraccount@localhost //command for vpn to connect to pi
```

This works great, but using this method, if I was to implement it, I would run into a few issues:

1. I would need to set up unique unused ports
2. Some way to keep these ports / tunnels opened
3. I need to come up with a system to identify each device. I can log each port to a name in like a text file locally? It would be beneficial to be able to include that in the ssh setup for each device if possible. I would still need to make sure the ports I use are not being used by any other programs or any device already there.

**What I don't want to have to do**

1. Check what ports are free to use for each RPI
2. Have to manually edit `.ssh/config` to add a name to represent each port assigned to RPI from part 1 above.

I am writing this for information/assistance as to what to do for my goal.

Could anyone provide me with a suitable solution?

Comment: Why are you being charged to use OpenVPN? There should be no cost unless you've taken out a support contract or you're using someone's server implementation as an endpoint. Neither seems necessary from your description here.

Comment: Hi, i am using openvpn access server? By default you get 2 concurrent free users. After that you need to pay for additional users (concurrents) It states its 10 licences for 1 year 150USD. I havnt paid but i have over 100 units not online due to this cost, i have 2 devices currently using openvpn (Since the 2 is free).

Comment: @A.B Looking for a solution to remove socket i found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427189/how-to-cleanup-ssh-reverse-tunnel-socket-after-connection-closed Here is a solution that works with `StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes`. I followed and your solution now works a charm! I just need to make sure the connection stays live! Might use autossh for that. Need to test a few things of course as reading it states it overrides previous session or something? Thanks though! Will keep posting as i go along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using OpenSSH >= 6.7 + [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

1. OpenSSH >= 6.7 can use [Unix domain socket forwarding](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7)

   That means the reverse tunnel endpoint will be an [UNIX listening socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) instead of a traditional TCP listening socket. You can then manage more easily the flotilla of RPIs with an easy naming scheme: the socket's name will be the RPI's chosen (and fixed) name, like `OfficeDevice1991`. It could be even be an unique property from the RPI as long as it's a valid filename (since unix socket names adhere to filename conventions). For example its hostname, the MAC address of its ethernet or wifi card ...

   SSH can handle unix sockets for tunnels, not for connecting itself. It will need the help of a `ProxyCommand` to be able to work as unix-socket client. [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can handle many kind of connections, including unix sockets.

   UPDATE:
   There is also a specific issue to handle: the unix socket file is not deleted on clean exit, nor would it have been be deleted anyway for example after a crash. This require the option `StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes`. I didn't find initially that, as the name perhaps imply, this option must be set on the node creating the unix socket. So in the end it's set on the client with a local forward (`-L`) *or else* on the server (in `sshd_config`) with a remote forward (`-R`). OP found it [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427189/how-to-cleanup-ssh-reverse-tunnel-socket-after-connection-closed). This solution uses a remote forward.

   Configuration on VPS:

   ```
   mkdir /rpi-access
   ```

   (as root) edit the `sshd_config` file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). It requires this additional option:

   ```
   StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
   ```

   Depending on default options it might also require `AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes`

   UPDATE2:
   Also set in `sshd_config` the parameters `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax`, thus allowing to detect a disconnect in a reasonable time, eg:

   ```
   ClientAliveInterval 300
   ClientAliveCountMax 2
   ```

   Stale ssh connections should then be detected earlier on the VPS (~10mn with the example), and the corresponding sshd process will then exit.

   Usage on RPI:

   ```
   ssh -fN -R /rpi-access/OfficeDevice1991:localhost:22 -i /privatekeyfile useraccount@ip
   ```

   In a config file this would be similar to this:

   ```
   Host ip
   User useraccount
   RemoteForward /rpi-access/OfficeDevice1991:localhost:22
   IdentityFile /privatekeyfile
   ```

   Repeating it again: the `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes` *set on `sshd` on VPS side* option is important: the socket just created is not removed, even upon normal exit. This option ensures that the socket is removed if it exists before use, thus allowing to be reused for further reconnections. This also means one can't consider the mere presence of the socket as meaning the RPI is connected (but see later).

   Now this allows to do on VPS:

   ```
   ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=socat UNIX:/rpi-access/%h -' rpiuseraccount@OfficeDevice1991
   ```

   As a configuration file, considering for example RPIs have all a name starting with *OfficeDevice*:

   ```
   Host OfficeDevice*
       User rpiuseraccount
       ProxyCommand socat UNIX:/rpi-access/%h -
   ```
2. To keep the link, just use a loop

   The RPI can run a loop reconnecting ssh to the VPS whenever the connections ends. For this it musn't use the background mode (no `-f`). A keepalive mechanism should also be used. TCPKeepAlive (system level) or ServerAliveInterval (application level) are available. I think TCPKeepAlive is useful only on the server (the side receiving the connection), so let's rather use ServerAliveInterval.

   Its value (as well as ServerAliveCountMax) should probably be adapted depending on various criteria: a firewall dropping inactive connections after a certain time, the wished recovery delay, not generating useless traffic, ... let's say 300s here.

   OfficeDevice1991 RPI:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   while : ; do
       ssh  -N -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -R /rpi-access/OfficeDevice1991:localhost:22 -i /privatekeyfile useraccount@ip
       sleep 5 # avoid flood/DDoS in case of really unexpected issues
   done
   ```

   Even if the remote side didn't yet detect the previous connectivity failure, and for a few more time has the old ssh connection still running, `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes` will anyway forcefully refresh the unix socket to the new connection.
3. it's already handled by 1.

   There's no `customcommandsearch` needed. With the right settings set in 1. just using `ssh OfficeDevice1991` will connect to OfficeDevice1991.

   If needed on the VPS, as `root` user only, this command:

   ```
   fuser /rpi-access/*
   ```

   can show which RPIs are currently connected (of course except those that recently lost the connection before detection). It won't show the stale unix socket files because there's no process tied to them.

Comment: For the loop section in keeping the client always connected to the VPS even after network issues, would it be better to us autossh here instead? If not, what do you suggest in doing with the provided code? Create a simple cron on startup then run the code or? Thanks.

Comment: I'm certain autossh is better than a simple shell loop. But having no experience with it, I can't give a solution using it. For the provided code, the best would probably to have it run from a systemd service (again I'm not very experimented at systemd service configuration so won't attempt it). Running it from a cron might require an other wrapper checking it's not running, or running it only at boot (`@reboot`)

Comment: Currently i have it on a @reboot. I may run it off systemd or give autossh a shot! I have experience around systemd etc but autossh is new to me! I love involving myself with new things so i may give that a shot first. Thanks!

Comment: Got a quick question, i noticed when i run something like "/bin/fuser /rpi-access/*", i notice the response i have multiple processes running beside each connected device? Seems to be due to connection issues and when the device disconnects and reconnects, it doesnt override the previous process but instead enters a new one? Why might this be? Any way of preventing this? Thanks!

Comment: That means two things: 1/ the detection by tools (fuser...) of unix socket users is a bit skewed when sockets were deleted. Just take a look at `fgrep /rpi-access/ /proc/net/unix`: you will see different unix sockets having the same name but a different inode. Luckily or this wouldn't have been found 2/ Indeed that probably means that one of the forked sshd process didn't exit when there was a network failure. OR that an unneeded ssh -fN command was run again on a RPI when it shoudn't have. I'll check what happens and will edit my answer later (maybe tomorrow)

Comment: Appreciate the help! If there is something that can overwrite the first process or basically have it so end result you will always see at least and only 1 process (not multiple) then that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Added a ClientAliveInterval parameter on VPS which should fix those sshd staying around (and a ConnectTimeout on RPIs in the loop, should avoid lengthy timeouts before retries)

Comment: You specified `ClientAliveCountMax` twice? Is it suppose to be: ClientAliveInterval 300 & ClientAliveCountMax 2. Thanks!

Comment: correction made

Comment: With the changes made, i no longer get stale processes! Worked a charm. Thing now is, i seem to get disconnected from my FTP while making changes to the file system. I use winscp? I guess from the changes made (ClientAliveCountMax & ClientAliveInterval) its now effecting my connection for FTP. Is it due to the interval or? Its not a big deal but is quite annoying when editing code xD

Comment: you mean sftp not ftp right? perhaps winscp doesn't support ClientAlive? try again with cygwin + sftp. or see if you can use the Match option in sshd_config to have this setting only apply selectively.

Answer (score 1):

This is a couple of different takes on the situation. I've omitted some of the detail here because there's nothing stopping you [asking a further Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for specifics if you try either of these routes.

**1. Replace OpenVPN Access Server**

If cost of OpenVPN Access Server is a prohibitive issue, consider deploying your own OpenVPN server. The software is free to use; you'd just need a server endpoint (a VPS or equivalent if you have nothing locally) and the skill-set to set it up. Many tutorials are available for that, so you don't need to start from ground zero.

Once you've got this set up you can use DNS or `/etc/hosts` to define host names such as your `OfficeDevice1991` to point to the appropriate VPN endpoint address on your server.

**2. Use `autossh` instead of OpenVPN**

Once you have your own endpoint you can use something like `autossh` on each of the Pi systems to `ssh` to a "well known" endpoint on boot (a VPS or equivalent if you have nothing locally).

Carry a reverse tunnel (`ssh -R`) across each, such that each Pi presents a different port number of your server that maps back to its own `ssh` port 22.

Judicious use of entries in `~/.ssh/config` can allow you to run `ssh OfficeDevice1991` and have it map automatically to something like `ssh -p 12345 localhost`, which in turn would correspond to a normal `ssh` connection to the Pi representing OfficeDevice1991.

---

Answering your set of questions you've added in your edit,

`who` or `finger` would give you each RPi's connected time.

1. Ports 49152 to 65535 [are yours](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335#section-6)
2. That's what `autossh` does
3. Hostnames

and

1. As #1 above
2. A short `for x ... do ... done` loop could autogenerate the file for you. I wouldn't want to create 1000 entries manually either.

Comment: `autossh` is the way to go. I'm running a dozen or so reverse SSH tunnels using this method. Some of them in fact chained because the originating network allows no direct connection to the outside world.

Comment: With the autossh solution, does this mean i need to manually assign ports and make sure these ports are not in use for each device i connect? If i have 1000 RPIs this also means i need to make sure that these 1000 ports i assign are all free before use? I would then need to go and config ssh with names that hooks to these ports. EG: RPI1 has port 1001 so i can type `ssh RPI1` and in my config it does the rest. I would then need to append 1000 records to config file for this? Am i wrong or if not.. Please say theres a better solution. Also, how can i get a list of active devices?

Comment: From my understanding this doesnt exactly give me an answer to my 3 issues listed in my question.

Comment: @irishwill200 answer updated to address your six questions