# Reverse SSH-Tunnel with Socket

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I would like to establish a reverse SSH-tunnel (with `OpenSSH_7.4` or newer). The purpose is to allow SSH-connections from a central server to multiple devices whose task it is (among others) to establish the tunnels. The central server has a known IP, while the devices do not.

I would usually do this in the following way on one of the devices

```
ssh -R "4001:server:22" -p 22 user@server
```

such that I can connect from the server to the device

```
ssh -p 4001 deviceuser@localhost
```

This works (and I do not need to know the IP-address of the device).

Now, I am not connecting a single device, but multiple, each of which creates a reverse tunnel and needs a separate port on the server. Furthermore, I want to connect repeatedly via ssh to each of them.

Thus, I had the idea to establish the reverse tunnel with a socket, like so:

```
ssh -R "~/tmp/device.sock:server:22" -p 22 user@server
```

In order to connect to the device from the server by

```
ssh -S ~/tmp/device.sock -p 22 deviceuser@device
```

I need the device's IP here, but that wouldn't be the major issue. However, I cannot seem to get that to work. The first command creates the socket, but with the second one I get errors such as

```
Control socket connect(/home/user/tmp/device.sock): Connection refused
```

The intended behaviour is that I can connect to the device through the tunnel, just like with the tunnel at port 4001 above, but based on the socket file. I cannot find any concise resources and wonder if, what I attempt, is in fact possible.

I assume that I could first create the tunnel to port 4001 and then an start an ssh control connection using a socket, but then I still need to use multiple ports on the server. There are enough ports available for my purposes, but I was hoping that there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: take a look at [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437151/251756) to a related question: [Information/Assistance required on reverse SSH Tunneling (Naming Conventions etc)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437032/information-assistance-required-on-reverse-ssh-tunneling-naming-conventions-etc/437151#437151)